# Имя и фамилия написанные наоборот должны распознаваться как одно лицо

Tags: mysql

День добрый. В базе есть поле со значением, например,  "Сергей Иванов". Нужно, чтобы запись "Иванов Сергей", распознавалась как дубль записи "Сергей Иванов". можно ли средствами **только** MySql сделать выборку, результатом которой будут id двух этих записей.

Comment: Вам нужны id всех дублей в таблице или только одного конкретного введённого?

Comment: мне нужно найти дубли всех пользователей

Comment: php в тегах для чего? Его нельзя ведь использовать по условиям вопроса.

Comment: У вас не такая простая задача: распознать варианты одного и того же имени. Смотрите, «Иванов Сергей» и «Сергей Петрович Иванов» — это тоже одинаковое имя. «Жан Даламбер» и «Жан д'Аламбер» — тоже. Туда же разница между «Наталия» и «Наталья». Вам придётся учитывать все эти варианты рано или поздно. Вы всё ещё надеетесь сделать это на уровне базы данных?

Comment: Так глубоко не нужно. Любые подобные варианты будут рассматриваться как разные люди. Интересует именно Имя Фамилия - Фамилия Имя. Если же нереально ее решить, используя только mysql, подскажите варианты решения, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.id AS id1, t1.name AS name1, t2.id AS id2, t2.name AS name2 FROM test t1, test t2
    WHERE NOT t1.id=t2.id
    AND 
    (
        t1.name = t2.name
        OR 
        (
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( t1.name , ' ', 1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX( t2.name , ' ', -1 )
            AND SUBSTRING_INDEX( t1.name , ' ', -1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX( t2.name , ' ', 1 )
        )
    ) GROUP BY CONCAT(LEAST(t1.id, t2.id),GREATEST(t2.id,t1.id))
```

Данные

```
"1","василий петров"
"2","петров василий"
"3","иванов сергей"
"4","иванов сергей"
"5","юля мальцева"
"6","мальцева юля"
"7","кирилл васечкин"
"8","сергей мямликов"
```

Вывод

```
id1 name1 id2 name2
2 петров василий 1 василий петров
4 иванов сергей 3 иванов сергей
9 сергей иванов 3 иванов сергей
9 сергей иванов 4 иванов сергей
6 мальцева юля 5 юля мальцева
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня отработало неверно из 17000 записей в результате 1300000

Comment: Отсеивать по `NOT t1.id=t2.id` не забыли? Иначе оно, естественно, склеит всех со всеми. Пример неправильного определения покажите. А лучше в вопрос структуру таблицы выложите.

Comment: @IK Я имел в виду пример неправильной выборки этого запроса. Типа "10, Василий Петров, 23, Геннадий Аллилуев"

Comment: у меня сомнения в правильности кода, который я составил - SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.name **FROM users AS t1, users AS t2** ....

Comment: 95692
Леванова ольга
60022
Леванова Ольга
86269
Ирина Гордиенко
60025
Гордиенко Ирина

Comment: @IK А что неправильно в этом выводе? ID разные, ФИО совпадают? Ровно как задача была поставлена. Я поправил ответ, чтоб дубли типа id1=1, id2=2 - id1=2,id2=1 не выводились.

Comment: @IK: Вы говорите, что сложный анализ не понадобится? Ну вот вам уже нужно уравнять «Ольга» и «ольга». Следом будет «Юля» и «Юлия», вангую.

Comment: @rjhdby Огромное спасибо. Проблема была из-за клиентов, которые так и назывались "Новый клиент". Почему-то их комбинации и давали такое количество записей. После их исключения, количество строк сократилось до 696 из 17000.

Comment: @rjhdby сопутствующий вопрос - этот запрос на сервере выполнялся 35 сек (с группировкой и без нее). Это непростительно долго. Можно его как-то ускорить?

Comment: @IK Например построить индекс по (id, name)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE people
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(100))
;

INSERT INTO people
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Сергей Иванов'),
    (2, 'Иванов Сергей')
;
```

Далее

```
    SELECT
     id
    FROM
      people
    WHERE 
      name ='Сергей Иванов' 
   or name =
        CONCAT(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX('Сергей Иванов',' ',-1),
     ' ',
     SUBSTRING_INDEX('Сергей Иванов',' ',1)
        );
```

Comment: А как сделать для всех записей, а не только для этих двух?

Comment: Откуда запрос вызываете, подставляете вместо Сергея Иванова нужные слова. Или вам вообще по всей базе нужно дубли найти?

Comment: Поиск по всей базе

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
     t1.id
    FROM
      people as t1
      INNER JOIN people as t2
      on t1.name = CONCAT(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.name,' ',-1),
     ' ',
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.name,' ',1)
        );